# How to create NSMutableDictionary in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

Recently i update Xcode to 7 and it contains swift 2.0 compiler. Before this i made my project with older version of swift. In that version i had create `NSMutableDictionary` like bellow

```
    let dictParams:NSMutableDictionary? = ["test" : "test", 
        "username" : txtEmail.text, 
        "password" : txtPassword.text, 
        "version" : "1.0", 
        "appId" : "1", 
        "deviceId" : "fasdfasdfrqwe2345sdgdfe56gsdfgsdfg"
    ];
```

in above code `txtEmail.text` and `txtPassword.text` is my text field and fill tha value at run time.

This code is properly working in older version of swift but after update to swift 2.0 it gives me an error like bellow

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to specified type 'NSMutableDictionary?'
```

what's wrong with it please guide me.

Comment: *Hint:* The question mark in `[String : String?]` is relevant. What type has `txtEmail.text` ?

Comment: Are you sure you need an NSMutableDictionary? Why not use a native Swift dictionary?

Comment: The txEmail.text or txtPassword.text, are they optional value? If so, would you mind unwrap them and check whether the error still exists.

Comment: @iamyogish That was the issue. thanks for update.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply by opening `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSDictionary` class interfaces from Xcode 7, you could easily see that the underlying type is actually `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. It means that the value can't be `nil`.

Unwrapping text values like `txtEmail.text!` or `txtPassword.text!` might look ok and help you to get rid of the compiling error, but it's a bad choice because technically `text` property of `UITextField` is optional and your app can crash in that case!

Do this for your safety:

```
let dictParams: NSMutableDictionary? = ["test" : "test", 
    "username" : txtEmail.text ?? "", // Always use optional values carefully!
    "password" : txtPassword.text ?? "",
    "version" : "1.0", 
    "appId" : "1", 
    "deviceId" : "fasdfasdfrqwe2345sdgdfe56gsdfgsdfg"
]
```

By the way, in case it's not critical to use `NSMutableDictionary`, please consider using Swift dictionary like this:

```
var mutableDictionary = [String: AnyObject] 

// OR this if the value can be nil
var mutableDictionary = [String: AnyObject?]
```

Comment: Thumbs up for null-coalesce operator `??`  instead of unwrapping with `!`

Answer (score 1):

simple change in
`"username" : txtEmail.text!` instead `"username" : txtEmail.text`

so final code is like bellow

```
let dictParams:NSMutableDictionary? = ["test" : "test", 
        "username" : txtEmail.text!,     //Add ! here 
        "password" : txtPassword.text!,  //Add ! here
        "version" : "1.0", 
        "appId" : "1", 
        "deviceId" : "fasdfasdfrqwe2345sdgdfe56gsdfgsdfg"
    ];
```

Comment: You just converted a compilation error into a runtime error, yay!

Comment: No, because textField.text is never nil! If you assign textField's text to nil, and inmediately print it out, it will print empty string, not nil. This is because internally .text converts nil values to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`txtEmail.text` and/or `txtPassword.text` are returning an optional which is why its telling you to change the type. You could rewrite the dict as a swift dictionary (which is what I would recommend). When you do so, you can either make the object optional, or leave it as just `String` and bang out the optional string when you're creating the dict.

```
var optionalString: String?

var someDict: [String: String?] = ["test": "test", "test1": optionalString]
```

Comment: Yes that is also another way to fulfil this but i have change minor in the existing code and it works. btw thanks for update :)